# Clustering by firm id (year, country, industry dummies) control variables to tackle heterogeneity==> enough?

Tags: least-squares

I’m focusing on managers characteristics (age education and narcissism) relationship with narratives reporting by firms.
(400 observations over 5 years , unbalanced , 6 countries )

Is doing the above procedures enough to valudate pooled ols regression results. I have taken lag DV as explanatory variable (was sig)

FE results was too low

Comment: Please I need help

Comment: Please, state your problem more clearly and what you refer to by "the above procedure".